# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mpl_toolkits.basemap' How to install Basemap

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, ipython, matplotlib-basemap

#### Error:

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
      2 import numpy as np
      3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
----> 4 from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mpl_toolkits.basemap'**

---

#### Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
%matplotlib inline
```

Comment: The most obvious reason for this would be that you haven't installed basemap at all, or at least not in the environment where you're trying to import it. How did you install it? Where do you run the code?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to install basemap by

```
conda install -c conda-forge basemap-data-hires
```